# Convert list items into a grid view

Tags: powershell

I would like a matrix / gridview of all my servers with the hotfixes installed. I query each server and get a list like this:

```
host1, fix1
host1, fix2
host1, fix3
host2, fix1
host3, fix1
host3, fix2
```

My grid would ideally look like:

```
HOSTS, fix1, fix2, fix3
host1, Yes, Yes, Yes
host2, Yes, No, No
host3, Yes, Yes, No
```

I think I should do this creating severall loops, but I usualy make a row like this:

```
$row = "" | Select Name, item1, item2
```

However, in this case, I don't know the number of items before I run the script. How can I size the $row dynamically?

***** EDIT *****
Created this version of the script by Mathias R. Jessen:

```
$ListOfAllHotfixes = @()
$fixesOnHosts = @()
$totalview = @()
$hyplist = Get-SCVMHostCluster -Name "CLH-LGF-CTX"  | Get-SCVMHost

foreach( $hyphost in $hyplist)
{
    $hotfixlist = Get-HotFix -ComputerName $hyphost  # Per host a list off installed hotfixes
    Foreach( $hotfix in $hotfixlist)
    {
        # Create list of just hotfixes to compare to later on
        $ListOfAllHotfixes += $hotfix.hotfixid 
    # Create rows of hotfixes per host
    $Row = "" | Select hostname, hotfix
    $row.hostname = $hotfix.PSComputerName
    $row.hotfix = $hotfix.HotFixID

    $FixesOnHosts += $row }
}

# $ListOfAllHotfixes is now filled with all fixes per host, let's make it unique on hotfixid
$ListOfAllHotfixes = ($ListOfAllHotfixes | Sort-Object -Unique)

# Result = $FixesOnHosts = all hosts and all their hotfixes
# Result = $ListOffAllHotfixes = unique list of the hotfixes

$HotfixesPerHost = @{}
foreach($Hotfix in $FixesOnHosts)
{
  $HotfixesPerHost[$Hotfix.Hostname] += @($Hotfix.Hotfix)
  write-host "Host = "  $Hotfix.Hostname
  write-host "Hotfix = " $hotfix.hotfix 
}


foreach($HypHost in $HotfixesPerHost.Keys)
{
  $Properties = [ordered]@{ Hostname = $HypHost }
  foreach($Hotfix in $ListOfAllHotfixes)
  {
    $Properties[$Hotfix] = $HotfixesPerHost[$HypHost] -contains $Hotfix
  }
  [pscustomobject]$Properties
}
```

However the result is like this:

```
Hostname  : VCDHYP636
KB2843630 : True
KB2868626 : True
KB2883200 : True
KB2887595 : True
KB2893294 : True
```

(25 lines of hotfixes)

```
Hostname  : VCDHYP609
KB2843630 : False
KB2868626 : False
KB2883200 : False
KB2887595 : False
KB2893294 : False
KB2894852 : True
KB2894856 : True
```

Answer (score 3):

To find out how many individual properties (or "columns") you need to specify, start by finding all distinct hotfixes - you can do this with `Sort-Object`:

```
$Hotfixes = @'
host1, fix1
host1, fix2
host1, fix3
host2, fix1
host3, fix1
host3, fix2
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Hostname,Hotfix

$DistinctHotfixes = $Hotfixes.Hotfix |Sort-Object -Unique
```

Now that we know which properties to create for each host, we just need an easy way of figuring out whether a given host has a specific hotfix installed or not.

We can easily do this by organizing all the entries by hostname:

```
$HotfixesPerHost = @{}
foreach($Hotfix in $Hotfixes){
  $HotfixesPerHost[$Hotfix.Hostname] += @($Hotfix.Hotfix)
}
```

Now we just need to generate the list of objects for our "matrix":

```
foreach($Hostname in $HotfixesPerHost.Keys){
  $Properties = [ordered]@{
    Hostname = $Hostname
  }
  foreach($Hotfix in $DistinctHotfixes){
    $Properties[$Hotfix] = $HotfixesPerHost[$Hostname] -contains $Hotfix
  }
  [pscustomobject]$Properties
}
```

And we end up with a nice list of hosts that, when piped to `Format-Table`, looks like this:

```
Hostname fix1  fix2  fix3
-------- ----  ----  ----
host3    True  True False
host1    True  True  True
host2    True False False
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive help. Your example works, but when I try to adept it to my situation it somehow goes wrong. Not sure if I'm mixing objects and strings, but the $properties export looks like this:
Name,Value
---------
Hostname,VCDHYP609
KB2843630,False
KB2868626,False
KB2883200,False
KB2887595,False
KB2893294,False
Can't get the formatting to work, but it is in a single table

Comment: Don't forget the last step (converting it into an object): `[pscustomobject]$Properties`

Comment: Yes, using that, but somehow the first line is the header line. You see first line is:  name, value. Second line is hostname, vcdhyp609 (which is the server name). Third line is hotfix and true/false.

Comment: If the "headers" are coming out as "Name" and "Value", it's because you _haven't_ converted the hashtable to objects yet :)

Comment: Changed my question to reflect my script based on yours. Can't see where my version is going wrong.

Comment: Ahh, I see - you need to pipe the output to `| Out-GridView` or `| Format-Table` (or export it to csv and import it into Excel)- PowerShell will format objects with more than 4 properties as a list by default :)